# Dismissing GKGameCenterViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, gamekit

I'll demonstrate my problem like this: I've a project with 2 classes- ViewController and GCManage.

The ViewController is a subclass of `UIViewController` and GCManage of `NSObject`.

When I push a button in ViewController it calls this method:

```
-(IBAction)showLeaderboards:(id)sender{
    GCManage *manageGC = [[GCManage alloc] init];
    if (manageGC.isGCenabled == YES){
        GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {
            gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = manageGC;
            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
            [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

For this instance, assume that `isGCenabled = YES`.

Now GCManage interface is

`@interface GCManage : NSObject <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>` (in h file, the first line).

I've implemented

```
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{
[gameCenterViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
[gameCenterViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
[gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
NSLog(@"Ran");
}
```

in GCManage but it doesn't appear to be called in any case.

Now when ViewController is the delegate of  and implements

```
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{

[gameCenterViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
NSLog(@"Ran");
}
```

it runs flawlessly. What's happening here?

Comment: In GCManage.h do you `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`
 and `#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>`? You said your GCManage definition is on the first line of the .h file.

Comment: Of course. I created this using xcode and imported: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface GCManage : NSObject <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in `ViewController` for your `GCManage` object. Your `manageGC` object created in `showLeaderboards:` is not being retained, and so the delegate function is never called.

Comment: Calling presentViewController will retain it

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm having a very similar issue and I cannot understand how to solve it. Could you take a look at my question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688134/cannot-dismiss-gkgamecenterviewcontroller-presented-from-skscene