# Cannot dismiss GKGameCenterViewController presented from SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I'm presenting a GKGameCenterViewController from an SKScene. This is my code:

```
-(void)showLeaderboardAndAchievements:(BOOL)shouldShowLeaderboard{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = _leaderboardIdentifier;

    // _spriteViewController references an UIViewController
    [_spriteViewController presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I don't have problems presenting the window, however I cannot manage to let users close it.  I implemented the method `gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish` however the function is not called at all. What do I have to do so users can close the leaderboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by adding the line `gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = _spriteViewController;`

```
-(void)showLeaderboardAndAchievements:(BOOL)shouldShowLeaderboard{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = _leaderboardIdentifier;
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = _spriteViewController; // er

    // _spriteViewController references an UIViewController
    [_spriteViewController presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

While it worked I got the warning:
`Assigning to 'id<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'UIViewController *__weak'`

For anyone in this situation the problem was simply that `_spriteViewController` was of type`UIViewController`, changing that to my custom class fixed the issue. You can also declare the property referencing the ViewController like this:

```
UIViewController <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> *_spriteViewController;
```